# How to use JsonRestStore with my RESTful service

Tags: javascript, dojo

I try to use dojox.data.JsonRestStore with my RESTful service. I read the articles by sitepen and dojox documentation but I can't understand what they are all about.
My service gets requests like `http://<host>/rest/relatedsuggestion?query=weath&results=3` and returns JSON

```
{
Suggestions: [
    “weather channel”,
    “weather forecast”,
    “weather bbc”
    ]
}
```

It means that it can't understand request like `http://<host>/rest/relatedsuggestion/3` which are used in every tutorial. How can I make it to understand my format? And as far as I understood the responce is also unusual for this class.

In order to try JsonRestStore I wrote the following mock up page, of cource it doesn't work and returns 4 errors "Type error: _57 is null":

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
    djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojox.data.JsonRestStore");
        dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");

        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
            var poStore = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({target:"http://<host>/rest/features/relatedsuggestion"});

            poStore.fetchItemByIdentity({
                identity:"3433",
                onItem:function(poItem){
                    poItem.completeOrder();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    />
</head>

<body class=" claro ">
    <div id="gridElement"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Kirill, correct me if im wrong, i think the fetch is async. So the  poStore.fetchItemByIdentity code should be inside the onComlete method of dojox.data.JsonRestStore.

Comment: I don't know about that, but there is no such event in the documentation (there are onDelete, onNew, onSet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This IBM developerWorks article might be of help: [Use Dojo's JsonRestStore with your REST services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wa-jsonreststore/?ca=drs-).

From your description, your service is non-standard, so you'll need to adapt both the URLs and the response mangling to fit what `JsonRestStore` expects. That article explains how you can do that by implementing your own service.